# How to disable date_select field of form when checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have defined these fields:

```
<%= f.label :acc_type, 'Trial mode' %>
<%= f.check_box :acc_type %>

<%= f.label :expire_date, 'Expire date' %>
<%= f.date_select :expire_date, { discard_day: true, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: (Date.today.year + 10), required: true }, class: 'form-control' %>
```

I'd like the expire_date to disable when I check the checkbox. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `jquery` to do this.
This is my idea, you can try.

For example:

```
<%= f.check_box :acc_type, id: "id_check_box" %>
<%= f.date_select :expire_date, { discard_day: true, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: (Date.today.year + 10), required: true }, class: 'form-control', id: "id_expire_date" %>


<script>
 $('#id_check_box').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
   $('select#id_expire_date').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
   $('select#id_expire_date').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 });
</script>
```